# Thead.join killing running thread java (kotlin)

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin

I have a Managed object (Dropwizard) which is processing an in-memory queue. When the shutdown signal is sent, i need to process the end of the queue. When i set the shutdown signal to true without joining the thread i can see if i put a sleep in my test that the items are processed. However when I join the thread it seems to stop the thread dead rather than waiting for the run method to finish.

```
 class LedgerProcessor constructor(
    private val ledgerProcessorQueue: LedgerProcessorQueue,
    private val paymentDao: PaymentDao) : Managed {

private lateinit var pollingThread: Thread

private val shuttingDown: AtomicBoolean = AtomicBoolean(false)


override fun start() {
    log.info { "Started Processing ledger requests" }
    pollingThread = object : Thread() {
        override fun run() {
            while (checkStatus()) {
                val payment = ledgerProcessorQueue.next()
                log.info { "Upserting payment ${payment.tokenId} status: ${payment.status}" }
                paymentDao.upsert(payment)
            }
        }
    }
    pollingThread.start()
}

private fun checkStatus(): Boolean  {
    val isShuttingDown = shuttingDown.get()
    val hasMore = ledgerProcessorQueue.hasNext()
    log.info { "isShuttingDown: $isShuttingDown, hasMore: $hasMore - ${!isShuttingDown || hasMore}" }
    return !isShuttingDown || hasMore
}

override fun stop() {
    shuttingDown.set(true)
    pollingThread.join() // this seems to stop the run in process
}
```

This test fails when pollingThread.join() is present but passes when no joining

```
    @Test
fun whenStartedButStoppedBeforeAllProcessedThenAllPaymentsInQueueShouldBeProcessedBeforeEnd(){
    val payment0 = aPayment()
    val payment1 = aPayment()
    val payment2 = aPayment()
    ledgerQueue.add(payment0)
    ledgerQueue.add(payment1)
    ledgerQueue.add(payment2)

    whenever(paymentDao.upsert(payment0)).then {
        ledgerProcessor.stop()
    }

    ledgerProcessor.start()
    //Thread.sleep(5000)

    verify(paymentDao).upsert(payment0)
    verify(paymentDao).upsert(payment1)
    verify(paymentDao).upsert(payment2)

}
```

Test Log with Thread.join on:

```
INFO   [12:02:44.734] [main] c.w.p.d.l.LedgerProcessor -  Started 
Processing ledger requests 
INFO   [12:02:44.738] [Thread-0] c.w.p.d.l.LedgerProcessor -  
isShuttingDown: false, hasMore: true - true 
INFO   [12:02:44.739] [Thread-0] c.w.p.d.l.LedgerProcessor -  Upserting 
payment 61a20508-37e6-4347-a7d1-2538fda8c470 status: Processing
```

test log with Thread.join off:

```
INFO   [12:04:41.994] [main] c.w.p.d.l.LedgerProcessor -  Started Processing ledger requests 
INFO   [12:04:41.999] [Thread-0] c.w.p.d.l.LedgerProcessor -  isShuttingDown: false, hasMore: true - true 
INFO   [12:04:41.999] [Thread-0] c.w.p.d.l.LedgerProcessor -  Upserting payment 5de161b7-3158-4ee4-a5d7-a690b3b500d6 status: Processing 
INFO   [12:04:42.004] [Thread-0] c.w.p.d.l.LedgerProcessor -  isShuttingDown: true, hasMore: true - true 
INFO   [12:04:42.004] [Thread-0] c.w.p.d.l.LedgerProcessor -  Upserting payment 741ab5ee-48af-426c-b167-97641286e796 status: Processing 
INFO   [12:04:42.004] [Thread-0] c.w.p.d.l.LedgerProcessor -  isShuttingDown: true, hasMore: true - true 
INFO   [12:04:42.004] [Thread-0] c.w.p.d.l.LedgerProcessor -  Upserting payment 79546c86-5d02-4bd7-91b8-c2e0c5c4eb5f status: Processing 
INFO   [12:04:42.004] [Thread-0] c.w.p.d.l.LedgerProcessor -  isShuttingDown: true, hasMore: false - false
```

Comment: `The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,
t.join();
causes the current thread to pause execution until t's thread terminates.`
taken from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html

So calling `pollingThread.join` will cause your current thread to pause execution until pollingThread is finished. My wild guess is that your checkStatus is having problems but I would like to ask for the log to see what get's logged and what not.

Comment: @Nico i have added the test log to the question. Thanks.